# c# ftp file into directory returns no access

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

```
public static void uploadMethod2()
        {
            FileInfo toUpload = new FileInfo("0000000002.csv");
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.myftp.co.uk/" + toUpload.Name);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
            **Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();**
            FileStream file = File.OpenRead("0000000002.csv");
            int length = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, length);
                ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            while (bytesRead != 0);
            file.Close();
            ftpStream.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("done");
        }
```

I got the above code from msdn but im a little confused over the webrequest.create line. the line ive put stars around returns the error 'no access or file not found', which i expect because there isnt a file called 0000000002.csv in the directory yet, but on the msdn website it says to add the file i want to upload along with the ftp url. ive tried without the file name appended to the url but this trhows a 'The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command' error. Ive tried the credentials in a browser(the ones in the above example are not the actual credentials of course) and i defintly gives me access to the directory. any ideas? any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried uploading the file using an FTP client? The browser test only proves you have read access. Just to make sure you're not overlooking anything - similar code works for me.

Comment: Turns out i didnt have write access. how dumb! sorry for wasting everyones time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to check directory access by using FileAccess enumerator before any operation on file. if it is only Read, then set directory attribute as Normal by using FileAttributes.

```
FileAttributes.Normal
```

hope this help you